# Auto Log In Users after registration and send confirmation email

Tags: email, user-registration

I'm using this function in functions.php to auto log in users after the sign up in the front-end

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
   wp_set_current_user($user_id);
   wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); 
   wp_redirect('http://mydomain.com/confirmation/');
   exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

This works great for auto login in users but for some reason this also causes the automatic confirmation email not being sent to users anymore. I have no idea why though, any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're short-circuiting the registration process when you redirect and exit script execution, the `user_register` action isn't the last step of the process. You can try to call [`wp_new_user_notification`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification) manually, but I'm not sure what other side-effects that may have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I added this line before the exit command. This sends an email to admin but it doesn't send an email to the registered user, is there a way to get the email to the user as well?

Comment: Okay I get it to work by removing the exit command from the function, but I'm getting the admin email twice for some reason for each user

Answer (score 0):

may be the `wp_redirect` causing the problem. you must call [wp_new_user_notification](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification) before the redirect.

May be a problem here - see the note on wordpress codex and the example in the codex

```
<?php wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass ) ?>
```

***Note: If password is not passed to function, the newly registered user will not receive their welcome email.***